# Is it possible to leave some textboxes empty to save data when using insert command parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

In the following example, I have to enter all the details to save the data in the database. Is it possible to leave some textboxes empty save it then use Update command parameters to fill out rest of the data? For example insert ID, AgeGroup, Gender, leave photo and Resume empty and save it in Access database? Could someone provide a example if the you don't mind. The description I have given you I don't know how to describe in technical terms? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Table1
                                    (ID, AgeGroup, Gender, CriminalOffence, photo, CV)   
                              VALUES(@ID, @AgeGroup, @Gender, @CriminalOffence, @photo, @Resume)", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeGroup", comboBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", comboBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CriminalOffence", OleDbType.WChar).Value = str;
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            //using MemoryStream:
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photo_aray);
        }
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Resume", richTextBox1.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
```

VS 2010 C#
Access 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a checking statement before submission:

for eg:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",  string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text.Trim())?  DBNull.Value:textBox1.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: I am looking for C# code. I have specify table column Required to No. So your answer is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Are you getting exception while submitting empty textbox values? if so, paste your error message here

Comment: The error I am getting is "No value given for one or more required parameters." OleDbException was unhandled

Comment: @Parveen - That looks better but I got a error of... "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string'"?

Comment: Then try String.Empty or  "0" for ID field instead of DBNull.Value

Comment: That looks good. I have tried on combobox and while it accepts null at front end and saves the value in Access. It seems combobox will show previous record saved data in the combobox in the new record?

Comment: Thank you Praveen. I created a empty collection in the combobox and now it is working perfectly. I really appreciated your expertise and your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass value to handle error "No value given for one or more required parameters".

it may be DBNull or empty string.

Comment: or if you have some special scenario Please explain more.

Comment: I am using MS Access 2003. So I need DBNull for OleDB

Answer (score 0):

have you set the `allow null` property to `true` for the columns that you wanna update later  in your database? if not do it and the current code of yours will work fine i guess..

```
string command = stirng.Format("INSERT INTO Table1(ID, AgeGroup) VALUES ({0},{1})",TextBox1.Text,ComboBox1.Text)
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, con)
```

Comment: specific fieldname has been set as Required to No. I am using MS Access 2003.

Comment: ok did you try formatting your command as i have shown above example??

Comment: Dude i told you not to set the Required to No for the primary key of your table... you can not have a row in database with primary key null

Comment: Sorry. I will try your method. please bear with me